# Programmatically identifying file type associations in Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, configuration, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, file-type

Is there any support in the *Windows* or *.NET for Windows Store apps* API:s that allow me to list which file type associations that are defined for the executing app?

In my scenario, I have a *Windows Store Class Library* that I intend to reference from various *Windows Store apps*. Ideally, I want to be able to read the defined file type associations of the app within a class library method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To date, there seems to be no built-in way to access the file type associations of a *Windows Store app*, but I have been able to implement a workaround thanks to [this](http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2013/01/examining-the-windows-store-apps-appxmanifest-at-runtime/) blog post.

Apparently the *Package.appxmanifest* file is transformed into a file *AppxManifest.xml* that is distributed with the deployed app. Among many things, the manifest file contains the user-defined file type associations for the app, so simple *XML* query can be used to obtain these definitions:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("AppxManifest.xml");
var xname = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest");

var fileTypeElements = 
    document.Descendants(xname + "FileTypeAssociation").Descendants().Descendants();
var supportedFileExtensions = 
    fileTypeElements.Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

This code can certainly be further fine-tuned, for example the *FileTypeAssociation* node is a (deep) descendant of the *Application* node, of which there can be more than one in the same manifest file. Nevertheless, the above code should at least be able to serve as a first-attempt approach.